# Generate signature using exponent and modulus in phpseclib

Tags: php, security, rsa, phpseclib

Trying to generate signature of plaintext using [PHPSECLib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib-php5)

```
$rsa = new \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA();
$modulus = '3vDug4ykxU62V4fcIFMuqrd71H92LiyRhOsiNAMqRK40qj4RYdMIXYGmqZq7oBXJ3GNQEBNqZ2t4D5004wY35yPx6LVFU54No6SdoE4E1fUB5gLrLAUcil0b-k_KN9gJNndcfYyUIKwRJywUQda35pwiTI1tvE41_Lk6HGOLtSauh7ichwgghbCZFzc_Gx0XWrBUXWhYCCW2_CTPWWqfhNI7qMJvBqfmoOunMD_pIozrkGUx6dgaIjbaICBJCEheFFiwHqYRUOXHCHxsKRBzHx-5vlsedj5HnI3FMOF9yNbafwk_SfPZQrZC0T7OwQzOmj9IngRGOmg3lwuDlSCcwQ';
$exponent = 'AQAB';
$public = [
    'n' => new \phpseclib\Math\BigInteger($modulus, 16),
    'e' => new \phpseclib\Math\BigInteger($exponent, 16),
];
$rsa->loadKey($public);
$text = 'RohanSakhale';
$signature = $rsa->sign($text);
var_dump($signature);
```

Getting empty signature here, please suggest what step is going wrong here.

Comment: What'd really help is seeing what you were using as your modulus and exponent. In lieu of having seen that my guess is that your modulus isn't large enough. The modulus needs to be 2 * hash length + 2 bytes long. At least. By default RSA uses sha1 (for phpseclib 1.0/2.0) so that'd be 42 bytes long. Is that how long your modulus is?

Comment: Roughly I just analysed its 342 bytes long, updating the same in question above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the second parameter of the `BigInteger` constructor is 16 that's telling `BigInteger` to assume that the strings are hex encoded numbers. But your strings aren't hex encoded - they're base64-encoded. The second character of the modulus is `v`, for example. That's not a valid hex character. Try this:

```
$rsa = new \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA();
$modulus = '3vDug4ykxU62V4fcIFMuqrd71H92LiyRhOsiNAMqRK40qj4RYdMIXYGmqZq7oBXJ3GNQEBNqZ2t4D5004wY35yPx6LVFU54No6SdoE4E1fUB5gLrLAUcil0b-k_KN9gJNndcfYyUIKwRJywUQda35pwiTI1tvE41_Lk6HGOLtSauh7ichwgghbCZFzc_Gx0XWrBUXWhYCCW2_CTPWWqfhNI7qMJvBqfmoOunMD_pIozrkGUx6dgaIjbaICBJCEheFFiwHqYRUOXHCHxsKRBzHx-5vlsedj5HnI3FMOF9yNbafwk_SfPZQrZC0T7OwQzOmj9IngRGOmg3lwuDlSCcwQ';
$exponent = 'AQAB';
$public = [
    'n' => new \phpseclib\Math\BigInteger(base64_decode($modulus), 256),
    'e' => new \phpseclib\Math\BigInteger(base64_decode($exponent), 256),
];
$rsa->loadKey($public);
$text = 'RohanSakhale';
$signature = $rsa->sign($text);
var_dump($signature);
```